# How to roll out MLGPO's via scripts in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, group-policy

I have some settings which must be defined per user in Windows 10 via Local Group Policy Objects. My workstations are on a Workgroup all running Windows 10 and so to do this I must use Multiple Local GPO's (MLGPO's).

I can define any MLGPO via the Microsoft Management Console (MMC). Setting MLGPO's in not the issue. I have a list of settings which I want to define for the Admin account and another list of settings for non-admin users (such as access to the Task Manager).

This method is rather slow if I have to do this for every workstation. Is there a way of rolling out MLGPO's via a script?

I have read that the [Windows 10 LGPO.exe](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/) does not support MLGPO. Is there any way of scripting the rollout of MLGPO in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

In general, GPO's just edit the registry settings. So basicly exporting those settings from registry to a .reg file will do the job and can be imported on other computers. You can use batch files to check for admin and then import one or the other .reg file.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights